# Python Recursion Error - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array

Using Python 2.7, I'm trying to write a code to recursively replace elements of a 2-dimensional list. Here is a code snippet of the function:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

def assimilate(population, x, y, influence):
    """Replace adjacent list elements recursively with -1 if cell is 
    lesser than the adjacent influenced cell.

    Keyword arguments:
    population -- 2D list of integers
    x -- x-coordinate of influencing cell
    y -- y-coordinate of influencing cell
    influence -- value of influencing cell

    Returns:
    Modified population list.
    """

    if population[y][x] <= influence:
        population[y][x] = -1
    if population[y][x] == -1:
        # Check adjacent cells
        if y - 1 > 0:
            if population[y - 1][x] <= influence:
                population = assimilate(population, y - 1, x, influence)
        if x + 1 < len(population):
            if population[y][x + 1] <= influence:
                population = assimilate(population, y , x + 1, influence)
        if y + 1 < len(population):
            if population[y + 1][x] <= influence:
                population = assimilate(population, y + 1, x, influence)
        if x - 1 > 0:
            if population[y][x - 1] <= influence:
                population = assimilate(population, y, x - 1, influence)
    return population
```

The objective of the code is to replace adjacent list elements (up, down, left and right, no diagonal) to `-1` if its value is less than or equal to the value of `influence`. It needs to iterate until all possible cells in range is converted.

An example of this is:

```
In: assimilate([[0, 1, 2], [8, 4, 5], [6, 7, 3]], 0, 0, 5)
Out: [[-1, -1, -1], [8, -1, -1], [6, 7, -1]]
Out (as a 2D list, visualized):
-1 -1 -1
8 -1 -1
6 7 -1
```

With the code, inputting 5 to `influence` results in a wrong output, and increasing the value of `influence` results in either `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` (Fixed by adding `import sys` and `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` or `Internal error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Three questions:

- What is wrong with how recursion was implemented?
- Is there a better way to iterate through the list while checking adjacent values?
- What could be a possible solution for the error?

Recursion is not mandatory, other alternatives could be used. I tried using a `while` loop but it still had wrong outputs. I'm trying not to use 3rd-party packages as much as possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using nested if statements instead of and?

Comment: Another question, I'm not sure what the goal output is here.  You say you want to replace adjacent list elements, but it looks like you want to just replace the list element that is less than influence?

Comment: @ekrah I forgot to remove the nested if statements while I was debugging, but essentially the same logic follows. The goal output is what I've written in the example. All values that are **less than or equal to** the value of `influence` that are adjacent to a cell that is valued `-1`. That's why I tried recursion because the code needs to run until all values adjacent to a `-1` and are less than or equal to `influence` needs to be changed to `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of Python, rather it's a logical error.

There is a problem in the logic here (and in other similar places),

> if population[y][x] <= influence:
>
> ```
>     population[y][x] = -1
> ```

Lets say,

> population[3][2] = -1

. Now, in the recursive process, when the program will come to

> population[3][1] , it will see that it's adjacent cell > (population[3][2])

is lesser than the influence value. If influence is positive, it will be true FOREVER. Thus it will again go to the > population[3][2]  cell which is already visited once. Thus the recursion call will become infinite.

To check this, you can change the line like this:

> **if population[ y ][ x ] <= influence and population[ y ][ x ] != -1 :
>           population[y][x] = -1**

Please let know if this solution works or not. You will have to change this logic in every place of the if condition

**EDIT (with Correction)**

When it visits a cell and makes it -1, it will not come to that cell again and will stop recursion. I implemented this and the recursion stopped. But this has also a problem. If a cell which is valid to be -1 becomes surrounded by values higher than influence, it will never be visited.

Consider below example:

```
influence=5

[ 9, 9, 2 ]
[ 9, 9, 9 ]
[ 9, 9, 9 ]
```

In this example, the cell of 2 will never be visited if we check only with -1. Because, 2 is surrounded by 9 and 9 will never be replaced by -1.

To remedy this, we need another array which will keep track of visiting. The array will be initialized to 0.  If a cell is already visited, its value will be 1 and a visited cell will never be revisited.

Check the code below. Its working fine.

```
import sys
def assimilate(population, visited, y, x, influence):
    visited[y][x] = 1

    if population[y][x] <= influence:
        population[y][x] = -1
        # Check adjacent cells
        if y - 1 >= 0:
            if visited[y - 1][x] != 1:
                population = assimilate(population, visited , y - 1, x, influence)

        if x + 1 < len(population):
            if visited[y][x + 1] != 1:
                population = assimilate(population, visited ,  y , x + 1, influence)

        if y + 1 < len(population):
            if visited[y + 1][x] != 1:
                population = assimilate(population, visited ,  y + 1, x, influence)

        if x - 1 >= 0:
            if visited[y][x - 1] != 1:
                population = assimilate(population, visited ,  y, x - 1, influence)

    return population

print assimilate( [[0, 1, 2], [8, 4, 5], [6, 7, 3]] , [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] , 0 , 0 , 5 )
```

**Output:**

```
[[-1, -1, -1], [8, -1, -1], [6, 7, -1]]
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, I included Python in the name because this was written in Python but I'm not completely sure which part of the code I'm missing. I've actually tried the `population[y][x] != -1` condition before on the individual adjacent checks but it didn't work. Trying out your proposed solution didn't fare better. I'm not really sure why but the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` kicks in whenever `influence` increases.

Comment: I have recoded this. Please check edit in my answer.

Comment: Your modified code works fine but then again you also modified the function parameters, which kind of defeats the purpose. I agree with the addition of `=` for the range. Actually, I already solved this problem albeit with loops, I was just curious how this would be implemented in recursion. Your solution is an interesting twist on the problem. However, changing the  parameters deviates from the original objective.

Comment: If you want to use recursion, then another array for visit tracking is required. otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: I'm sorry @late_riser but I have to disagree. Having solved this using loops, I'm inclined to believe that recursion could be done with the same exact parameters. However, I thank you for taking the time to indulge my question.

Comment: You are welcome. But, I am curious to know how could it be done with recursion but without additional array to keep track. Please let me know when you can solve. I am really curious to know. Thanks for your support and appreciation. :)